# How to run ansible command in PowerShell?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, ansible

I have installed Python using Choco in PowerShell on windows. It works.

```
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I also installed `ansible` from pip

```
ansible==2.3.0.0
```

But when I run `ansible` from PowerShell, Windows ask me how to open the program and give me a windows programs select list. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it using Python on Windows. It is not supported nor planned.

You can run a Linux virtual machine.

Some people managed to run Ansible in Cygwin, but it's not officially supported.

---

Refer to  [Using a Windows control machine](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#using-a-windows-control-machine):

> A Linux control machine is required to manage Windows hosts.
>
> [ ]
>
> Running Ansible from a Windows control machine directly is not a goal of the project. Refrain from asking for this feature, as it limits what technologies, features, and code we can use in the main project in the future.

---

That said, the direct reason for `ansible` not being run is probably the fact that it doesn't have an extension associated with Python. But fixing this won't allow running Ansible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

just to add to the existing answer, ansible works perfectly fine with WSL\Bash on Windows. I've managed to get Vagrant + Ansible working on WSL. And I didn't really have to do anything special.

SSH works\Ansible provisioner works\Vagrant works